# Confusing error from | xargs sed

Tags: git, bash, replace, sed, xargs

I have a little find-replace utility around `git`. Let's ignore suggestions for a different approach ATM. I'm really trying to understand this error from `sed`. Take a look at the command

```
function git_find_replace
{
    local grepexp="$1"
    local replace="$2"

    # build sed command
    local sedcmd="s/$grepexp/$replace/g"

    # First find the files; then pipe through xargs sed for replacement
    git grep --name-only "$grepexp" | xargs sed -r "$sedcmd" -i ''
}
```

The command works, and I get the expected results, however, when I run this on one of my repositories, I get an error from `sed`

```
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

But the `git` component returns a set of files that all exist (slightly mangled for sake of post)

```
git grep --name-only 0.46.1
release/a.html
release/resources/javascript/a.js
release/resources/version
release/index.html
release/installer.html
```

I've verified the existence of these files manually with `ls`. For example, if I change the `xargs` component to this

```
git grep --name-only 0.46.1 | xargs ls -l
```

There are no complaints from `ls` about missing files or directories. So why do I get an error from `sed`?

### Update

To save you some digging through the answers and comments, this turned out to be a difference between BSD and GNU versions of `sed`. See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/476575/replace-os-xs-shell-commands-with-the-linux-versions) for more.

Comment: What is the `''` for at the end of the sed command?

Comment: No extension in the for the `-i` component. It edits the files in place rather than put the edits in temp files w/ a different extension.

Comment: It means not to create backup files when editing.

Comment: Does it work better if you put `-i ''` before the `"$sedcmd"`?

Comment: run the script with `bash -x` and you get a idea what went wrong. IMHO, something when calling the `git_find_replace`... and your `sedcmd` contains something wrong...

Comment: also turn on shell debugging/trace with `set -vx`. AND  you will encounter fewer problems if you use another char beside '/' to delimit your sed sub/replace . Maybe `local sedcmd="s@$grepexp@$replace@g"`, you may need `"s\@....@"`. Good luck.

Comment: @Barmar No. If I try `git grep --name-only 0.46.1 | xargs sed -r -i '' 's/0.46.1/0.48.0/g'` or `it grep --name-only 0.46.1 | xargs sed -i '' -r 's/0.46.1/0.48.0/g'`, the error becomes `sed: can't read s/0.46.1/0.48.0/g: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. Somehow `sed` is seeing an extra argument somewhere, and this is confusing it about where the filename arguments start.

Comment: @Barmar I'm with you on your last comment, but unsure how to cope with it. Sadly `2>/dev/null` is likely what I'll do for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass an extension to `sed -i`, it needs to be adjoined to the `-i`, as in `sed -i.bak myfile`. It can't be a separate argument. `sed -i .bak myfile` would cause sed to do in place editing of files named `.bak` and `myfile`.

When you write `sed -i ''` sed tries to do in place editing on a file whose name is the empty string.

If you don't want backup files made, just leave off the argument entirely. No `''`.

```
git grep --name-only "$grepexp" | xargs sed -r "$sedcmd" -i
```

Comment: God knows why I was using an explicit `''`, but this does seem to solve the problem for me!

Comment: OIC - Looks like a difference between the versions of BSD and GNU `sed`! On my Mac, if I try your solution I get a different error from `sed` `sed: rename(): No such file or directory`, there I must supply the explicit `-i ''`. I'd first encountered the problem dropping this function on a Linux box today for the first time apparently. Good times!!!

Comment: Confirmed [on another thread](http://superuser.com/questions/476575/replace-os-xs-shell-commands-with-the-linux-versions) this was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer, it's a debugging step, but it's too long to put in a comment. Try creating a script called `print_args`:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for arg
do
    printf "Arg %d = '%s'\n" $i "$arg"
    ((i++))
done
```

Then try:

```
git grep --name-only "$grepexp" | xargs ./print_args sed -r "$sedcmd" -i ''
```

This should show all the arguments being passed to `sed`, you may see something that explains why sed is parsing it incorrectly.

Comment: Brilliant. I was wondering how to get `xargs` to show me what's going on. Let me give it a whirl.

Comment: This was very helpful, and I've given you a +1. After looking at the output though it seems `xargs` is passing all the files to `sed` in a single invocation. I'd expect `xargs` to call `sed` once for each file since they're newline delimited. Any idea why that's not the case?

Comment: That's how `xargs` is supposed to work. It only invokes the command multiple times if the number of arguments would exceed the system's limit. You can also use the `-n` option to set the argument limit, or use `-I str` to specify a placeholder string for the argument, in which case it does it once per file.

Comment: However, that in itself shouldn't cause this error from `sed`, as it allows multiple filename arguments.

Answer (score -2):

`sed` may be complaining because you are using the `s/foo/bar/` command on values of `$foo` and/or `$bar` that may contain the delimiter -- `/`.  Try `s%foo%bar/` or `s@foo@bar` or some other delimiter you're confident will not appear.

Comment: That would cause a different error, about syntax in the command. It wouldn't cause it to get confused about which argument is a filename.

Comment: That's definitely something to take under advisement in general, but it's not the problem here as the arguments are `0.46.1` and `0.48.0` for `$grepexp` and `$replace` respectively.